# How can I get process if it's already running?

Tags: vbscript, process

*For example:*

I have a code of VBS, it will help me check a program is already running

```
Function isProcessRunning(strComputer, strProcess)
    Dim Process, strObject
    strObject = "winmgmts://" & strComputer

    For Each Process In GetObject(strObject).InstancesOf("Win32_Process")
        If UCase(Process.Name) = UCase(strProcess) Then
            isProcessRunning = True
            Exit Function
        Else
            isProcessRunning = False
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

But, I want to get process is already running for re-using.

```
Function shell()
        If isProcessRunning(".", "cmd.exe") == False Then
            Dim objShell
            Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            shell = objShell.Run(cmd)
        Else
            shell = ...  'how can I get cmd.exe already running here
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

---

*Update my problem*

Actually, I want to get instance of `cmd.exe` if it's already running. I mean, I don't want re-open `cmd.exe` again.

Example:

1. I have just opened `cmd.exe`.
2. I run this code below (its name is `laucher.vbs`).

```vb
Function isProcessRunning(strComputer, strProcess)
    Dim Process, strObject

    strObject = "winmgmts://" & strComputer

    For Each Process In GetObject(strObject).InstancesOf("Win32_Process")
        If UCase(Process.Name) = UCase(strProcess) Then
            isProcessRunning = True
            Exit Function
        Else
            isProcessRunning = False
        End If
    Next
End Function

Function getProcessRunning(strComputer, strProcess)
    Dim Process, strObject

    strObject = "winmgmts://" & strComputer

    For Each Process In GetObject(strObject).InstancesOf("Win32_Process")
        If UCase(Process.Name) = UCase(strProcess) Then
            ... 'I do not know how to code this here for return instance of Process is running ...
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function

Function shell()
    If isProcessRunning(".", "cmd.exe") == False Then
        Dim objShell
        Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        shellFn = objShell.Run("cmd")
    Else
        shellFn = getProcessRunning(".", "cmd.exe")
    End If
End Function

Dim cmdExe
cmdExe = shell
cmdExe "shutdown -s -t 60"
```

Because `cmd.exe` is already running `cmdExe "shutdown -s -t 60"` will re-using cmd and execute command.

Comment: You could use similar code used in isProcessRunning function to get Process object and manipulate/inspect object with properties and functions described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Thank you for helping me, I tried to read your suggestions website, but I still not find solved my problem. If you have another suggest, please help me :D, Thank you again

Comment: @JoSerra I have just updated my question, please check it help me

Comment: Don't do what you're trying to do. You don't really gain anything from it anyway. Just run the command right away (`objShell.Run "shutdown -s -t 60"`).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I have a idea for writing a file execute a lot of command (auto to do something such as, start up a program, check network or disconnect, shutdown my computer with schedule ....), and file laucher.vbs can help me re-use cmd.exe. Besides I think I can re-use any process like singleton pattern here. Do you think it's possible?

Comment: Which part of "don't do what you're trying to do" wasn't clear enough before? Do not try to automate typing into a CMD window. Automate what you would otherwise type into the CMD window.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thank you so much. Maybe, I will try to keep it simple

Answer (score 2):

Give a try for this example :

```
Option Explicit
Dim ProcessPath1,ProcessPath2
ProcessPath1 = "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe"
ProcessPath2 = "%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
Call CheckProcess(ProcessPath1)
Call CheckProcess(ProcessPath2)
'**************************************************************************
Sub CheckProcess(ProcessPath)
    Dim strComputer,objWMIService,colProcesses,WshShell,Tab,ProcessName
    strComputer = "."
    Tab = Split(ProcessPath,"\")
    ProcessName = Tab(UBound(Tab))
    ProcessName = Replace(ProcessName,Chr(34),"")
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = '"& ProcessName & "'")
    If colProcesses.Count = 0 Then
        Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        WshShell.Run DblQuote(ProcessPath)
    Else
        MsgBox DblQuote(ProcessName) & " is aleardy running !", vbExclamation,_
        DblQuote(ProcessName) & " is aleardy running !"
        Exit Sub
    End if
End Sub
'**************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**************************************************************************
```

Comment: Thank you. I have just updated my question above. I want to get instance of process already running. May you help me, please

Comment: To return an object from a VBScript function you can assign object to function name with set command : Set getProcessRunning = Process. To receive object you must use set command again: set shellFn = getProcessRunning(".", "cmd.exe"). Otherwise, it has no sense to "reuse" cmd.exe process to execute shutdown command. You could execute shutdown command directly. Regards.